# Javascript/a:href not working on web music player

Tags: javascript, html

[image](https://i.gyazo.com/303d4b2d27f57639145ed2883aa17cf2.png)

I'm trying to set up the download button to download the song in the player but the button is completely ignored, it works like it doesn't do anything, lyrics button works fine but download is not working it plays the song instead as if I clicked on the player and not the download button

I tried using a link on the a:href tag thought it couldn't get the files from the server but turns out its a button issue

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 text-md-right">
<a href="music/dia elight - backwards.mp3" download class="btn-s btn with-ico"><i class="icon-download"></i>Download</a>

<a href="#" class="btn-s btn  with-ico  toggle-lyrics"><i class="icon-note" </i>Lyrics</a> 

</<div>
```

```
    // Track list player 

    var playlist = $('.album');
    var a = audiojs.create(playlist, {
        trackEnded: function() {
            var next = $('.playlist li.playing').next();
            if (!next.length) next = $('.playlist li').first();
            next.addClass('playing').siblings().removeClass('playing');
            audio1.load($('.as-link', next).attr('data-src'));
            audio1.play();
        }
    });

    var audio = a[0];
    var first = $('.playlist li .as-link').attr('data-src');
    $('.playlist li ').first().addClass('pause');
    audio.load(first);




    $('.playlist li').on("click", function() {
        if ($(this).attr('class') == 'playing') {
            $(this).addClass('pause');
            audio.playPause();
        } else {

            $(this).addClass('playing').removeClass('pause').siblings().removeClass('playing').removeClass('pause');
            audio.load($('.as-link', this).attr('data-src'));
            audio.play();
        }

        return false;

    });


    $('.toggle-lyrics').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('.playlist li').find('.block-lyrics').slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        return false;
    });
```

it shows the file and prompts to download (prompt on phone) when i open the button in the new tab but it doesn't work when clicking on it

It's supposed to download the mp3 file when clicking on the download button

Comment: Is the song hosted on the same domain (web server) as the webpage?

Comment: @Peter B yes it is

Comment: it shows the file and prompts to download (prompt on phone) when i open the button in the new tab but it doesnt work when clicking on it

Comment: I found that the issue is in javascript but I don't know exactly what

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a "spaces" problem in the url `music/dia elight - backwards.mp3` because its a link, perhaps try replacing each space with `%20`

Also in your `Lyrics` button you have a missing `>` on your `i` tag, it might cause an issue aswell.

Let me know if this fixes it:

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 text-md-right">
<a href="music/dia%20elight%20-%20backwards.mp3" download class="btn-s btn with-ico"><i class="icon-download"></i>Download</a>

<a href="#" class="btn-s btn  with-ico  toggle-lyrics"><i class="icon-note>" </i>Lyrics</a> 

</<div>
```

Note: I'd suggest you renaming your hosted files to exclude spaces, like `music/die_elight_-_backwards.mp3` and then in your download button you can add:

```html
download="die elight - backwards.mp3"
```

instead of simply `download`

Comment: Did not fix, it does show that the download button is redirecting to the file link but it just ignores it when clicking it plays the song like the download button is invisible